# When I click a button on a webpage, how to pass the value of that button as a parameter of a function?

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm working in a project recently it is about the rock paper scissor game. I'm stuck in a problem that when I click on one of the three buttons (which are rock, paper, or scissors) the `addEventListener` does work but one of the actual parameters of a function that I'm passing as a parameter to the event listener "the console said it is undefined".

I just want when clicking the button to pass the value of that button to this parameter I'm talking about.

```js
const rock = document.querySelector('.rock');
const paper = document.querySelector('.paper');
const scissors = document.querySelector('.scissors');
// there are some functions
let computerSelection = computerPlay();

rock.addEventListener('click', function(){
playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
});

paper.addEventListener('click', function(){
playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);});

scissors.addEventListener('click', function(){
playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);});
```

```html
<button class="rock">ROCK</button>
<button class="paper">PAPER</button>
<button class="scissors">SCISSORS</button>
```

Comment: In `playRound()` use `const clicked = event.target` `let value = clicked.value`. Add a `value` to each button. BTW, I can't tell with what you posted, but you pass the `event` object by default, what are the those two params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read the event on each click listener and you can extract the value from the event by `ev.target.value`:

```
anyButton.addEventListener('click', function(ev) { 
  playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection, ev.target.value);
}
```

This, of course, implies that your buttons all have a `value` attribute set.

As an improvement, you could add add event listeners at once without going through each element:

```
const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button') // adjust this per your DOM
allButtons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function(ev) { 
    playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection, ev.target.value);
  })
})
```

Comment: I would prefer using an arrow function for the eventlistener as well, but it's pretty much the answer!

Comment: @ak.leimrey true

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass playSelection according to wich button the player has clicked:

```
rock.addEventListener('click', function(){
playRound('rock', computerSelection);
});

paper.addEventListener('click', function(){
playRound('paper', computerSelection);});

scissors.addEventListener('click', function(){
playRound('scissors', computerSelection);
});
```

But I have a suggestion to do that with only one event handler. First you'll have to say in each button what choice it represents. Do that using data- attributtes (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes):

```
<button class="rock choice-button" data-choice="rock">ROCK</button>
<button class="paper choice-button" data-choice="paper">PAPER</button>
<button class="scissors choice-button" data-choice="scissors">SCISSORS</button>
```

Note that I added a `choice-button` class to each button, so you can access all three at once when adding the event:

```
// there are some functions
let computerSelection = computerPlay();

document.querySelectorAll('.choice-button')
        .forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            playRound(event.target.dataset.choice, computerSelection);
         }));
```

First I use `querySelectorAll` to find all elements that matches the `choice-button` class, then i use `forEach` function to iterate trought all 3 found buttons and add the same event listener to all of them.

Once the event listener is executed, I used 'event.target' to get access to the clicked button, and called the dataset property to get the value defined in the `data-choice` attribute.

I know it might seem a bit overhead for only three choices, but since you seem to be learning javascript, its interesting to learn different approaches that might help you in a more complex situation.

Answer (score 0):

The `undefined` error (and two more that follow it once the initial one is fixed) is caused because you are referencing a function that has not been declared:

```
let computerSelection = computerPlay();
// computerPlay() is not defined;
```

If you create the `computerPlay()` function, the error will go away but a new one will appear because `playRound()` is also not defined. Again, the function must be declared if it is referenced (although hoisting allows it to be declared after the call in this case).

When that is fixed, the last error arises by the reference to `playerSelection` as, again, this has not been declared. Assuming the value of `playerSelection` is to be rock, paper, or scissors, you have to extract it from the click event.

The event handler needs to extract the `innerText` property value of the event's `target`. Inside you're event listeners you need:

```
playerSelection = event.target.innerText;
```